# Spring Integration @Autowired not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I am using @Autowired to get create the Bean. But i am getting NullPointer and the Bean is not getting created.

Spprinng Stater

```
@ComponentScan("com.api")
public class DoseManagementApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DoseManagementApplication.class, args);
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/integration.xml");
    DoseManager doseManager = (DoseManager) context.getBean(DoseManager.class);

    doseManager.doseMangement("");

    context.close();

}
```

}

Integration.xml

```
<int:gateway id="doseManager" service-interface="com.cerner.api.gateway.DoseManager"/>

<int:channel id="requestChannnel"></int:channel>

<int:service-activator ref="doseManagerServiceActivator" input-channel="requestChannnel" method="buildDoseMedRelation"> 
</int:service-activator>
<bean id="doseManagerServiceActivator" class="com.cerner.api.activator.DoseManagerServiceActivator"></bean>
```

DoseManager Interface

```
package com.api.service;    
@Component
public interface DoseManager {

@Gateway(requestChannel="requestChannnel")
public void doseMangement(String startMsg);
}
```

Service Activator Class

```
package com.api.service;
@Component
public class DoseManagerServiceActivator {

@Autowired
private DoseManagerService doseManage;

public void buildDoseMedRelation(Message<?> msg) {
    System.out.println("doseManage== "+doseManage);
}
}
```

Service Class

```
package com.api.service;
@Service
public class DoseManagerService {

}
```

I am trying to figure out why the @Autowired is not working. but didn't get any success. There is nothing the Service class.

Comment: Where's `DoseManagerService` ? its name should be `doseManager`?

Comment: This is my service class. For now i don't have any implementations in that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498104/could-we-autowire-an-interface-without-any-implementation-in-spring

Comment: I have added the service class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you use a plain `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/integration.xml");`, but not that one with annotations support.

It is not clear why you create a new application context at all since it looks like you are in Spring Boot, because you that `SpringApplication.run(DoseManagementApplication.class, args);`. From here your integration configuration is loaded in the separate `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and is fully not visible for Spring Boot.

I would suggest you to use a `@SpringBootApplication` on your `DoseManagementApplication` together with the `@ImportResource("classpath:/integration.xml")` and then call `getBean()` (if you need) from the `ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DoseManagementApplication.class, args);` and don't use an `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` at all.

Comment: I had tried this @ImportResource("classpath:/integration.xml") ealier but i was not knowing that we can get the ApplicationContext from the SpringApplication.run . Thanks for the help. Its working fine.